# how to change icon when pressed also change screen according to icons in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Question is simple that if I click on button his icon should be changed also according to icons Switch widget into another widget, how it can be possible,

```
FlatButton(
                onPressed: ()
                {
                 change ? play() :pause();
                },
                child: change?new Icon(Icons.pause):new Icon(Icons.play_arrow)
              )

Widget play()
  {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black38,
      height: 200,
      child: Text("Play"),
    );
  }

  Widget pause()
  {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white10,
      height: 200,
      child: Text("Pause"),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FlatButton{
  onPressed: (){
    change = !change;
    setState(() {});
  }
  child: change ? play() : pause(),
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution a bit!?

Comment: change holds a bool for pause and play, when clicked to button it needs to change its opposite, and there are widgets need to rebuild for pause and play icon, so we need to setState after we change "change" to opposite,